# Multiple NSFetchedResultsController's with one UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Visually I have a `UITableView` with a `UISegmentedControl` to allow 'mode' selection which will change the table's sort order .

Using `NSFetchedResultsController`'s I am thinking I should keep a separate controller for each different sort configuration then swap between which one is being displayed based on the currently selected 'mode'.

However I can see this will get tricky with 4 different `NSFetchedResultsController` all sending delegate messages to update the `UITableView`. To deal with this I am planning to use a `switch()` block in each of the relevant methods to ignore all but the currently 'active' `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Does this sound like the right approach or am I missing something obvious here?

-I can see potential for disaster if the user changes the 'mode' just as an update comes through (ie between `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a segment control to change sorting/grouping in several Core Data apps. In all of them, I've always just used a single NSFetchedResultsController, and re-queried the database when the segment changes.

As you correctly realized, it is a far simpler implementation that way, fewer chances of unexpected errors, and is also more **scalable**. E.g. what if I decide to add a new sorting/grouping segment based on customer feedback? How many NSFetchedResultsController's are you going to keep adding? At some point (5 or 6) it just becomes ridiculous.

Also graver's comment above that you could set all of their delegates, except the "active one" to nil won't scale (you would have to modify many lines of code to make all the other delegates nil, which will make maintaining the code hard.

So my suggestion is to go with the simpler implementation, which is a single NSFetchedResultsController, and recreate it every time the segment changes. If you're interested in caching, you could use a separate cache name for each segment. A unique cache name can be generated for each segment by concatenating something like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cache_%d", segment_index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it more logical when the segmented control's selected index is changed, to change the sort descriptors and performFetch?

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray ... ];
```

Comment: At the expense of losing the caching of each mode though. Although I can see how this is a vastly simpler approach than trying to juggle 4 simultaneously

Comment: Are dependent of the cache, actually? And why don't you try when switching the segment, to set the controller you currently use delegate to self, but the other three to nil. then your delegate methods will fire only for the active controller...